# Storing to database in sqlalchemy with no values

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying an api in sql alchemy in which i am storing details of courses into database. The below code is the one i am using in which course name, start date, end date and hours per day are from the form. Start date and end date are optional. So it can be none. But i cant store the value to database with null values.

course_db = Course(course=course, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, hours_per_day=hours)

My model is

class Course(Base):
    **tablename** = 'courses'

```
id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
course = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
start_date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
end_date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
hours_per_day = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

def __repr__(self):
    return "Course(%r)" % (self.course)
```

Can some one help me to sort this out. I am using postgresql as my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Insert **init** in models

class Course(Base):

```
__tablename__ = 'courses'

id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
course = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
start_date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
end_date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
hours_per_day = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

def __init__(self, course, start_date=None, end_date=None, hours_per_day=None):
    self.course = course
    if start_date:
        self.start_date = start_date
    if end_date:
        self.end_date = end_date
    if hours_per_day:
        self.hours_per_day = hours_per_day

def __repr__(self):
    return "Course(%r)" % (self.course)
```